# Can a UK indefinite leave to remain sticker in an expired passport be used alongside a valid passport for travelling?

Tags: visas, uk

I am a UK national as are all my children, but my wife is not. She does however have an indefinite leave to remain sticker in her old expired passport. Will she still be able to travel, using her old and new passports together?

Answer (score 6):

The [UKVI explains what to do](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa):

> You can still use your visa even if your passport’s expired, but you can choose to replace it with a biometric residence permit (BRP) if you’re in the UK.
>
> You must replace your visa with a BRP if your name or personal details change.
>
> **If your passport has expired**
>   You can still use the valid visa in your expired passport, but you’ll need to show your expired passport and your new passport when you’re travelling to and from the UK.
>
> If you’re in the UK, you can [apply for a BRP](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa/transfer-to-brp) instead.
>
> If you’re outside the UK, you can [transfer your visa to your new passport](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa/transfer-to-passport).

Comment: I can confirm this is not merely theoretical.  My wife did it for many years, each time getting a "VIPP" (Visa In Previous Passport) note alongside her entry stamp.

Answer (score 3):

Your wife can continue to travel with her existing ILR provided she carries both expired and current passports when travelling to and from the UK
(Source:[Gov.UK Visas and Immigration](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa))

If you're in the UK you can apply to have a Biometric Residence Permit added to her new passport for a fee of GBP237 (!).
(Same source)

Comment: Thanks for the invaluable advise, it's definitely put my mind at ease. I will be travelling abroad around mid-March and unfortunately the only way to get a BRP between now and March is if I pay £600 on top of the £240 fee for a BRP. I think this is way over the top. I will apply for a BRP when I get back to the UK. I wont need to pay the £600 fee, as I don't mind waiting 6 months for the BRP application to be processed.